# Self-hosted Gitlab-Runners IP addresses

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been traversing Stack and the net in general (Gitlab documentation is a no-brainer) but I can't seem to find any info related to if there's a way to set static ip to the gitlab-runner(s) itself through configuration, or any way in general.

Context:
I've hosted my runners on cloud (single VM) with a static IP for the VM itself.
Theoretically, whitelisting the possible CIDR is dangerous because it's too wide.

I'd appreciate any info, thank you in advance!